# Use pgdump sql file to upgrade version?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade, postgresql-14, postgresql-15

Can I use a pgdump `.sql` file generated by one version as a way to upgrade to another version?

For example:

If I created a backup on PostgreSQL 14 with:

```
pg_dump --no-privileges --no-owner $DB_NAME > $DB_BACKUP_FILE
```

Can I load it into PostgreSQL 15 as an effective way to upgrade to PostgreSQL 15?

```
sudo -u $DB_USER psql $DB_NAME < $BACKUP_FILE
```

Any drawbacks? Any chance of something not working properly after the import?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: It seems to work but I am just wondering if some things are not ported over in the new version. Overall, is it a reliable upgrade strategy or this should be avoided and the use of pg_upgrade is the way to go?

Comment: Hum actually, with pg15 behaving differently with public schema, I need to move everything to the new schema.

Comment: You don't need to move anything. Just re-grant the usage on the `public` schema to the role `public`

Comment: I wanted to re-align with the pg logic around schemas going forward but that's another topic to move schemas I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a possible way to upgrade. See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html#UPGRADING-VIA-PGDUMPALL) for details. Some things that may not become clear from the documentation:

- you have to perform dump and restore with database users that have the necessary permissions (using a superuser is the normal way to do that)
- if you use `pg_dump` rather than `pg_dumpall`, the backup won't contain the user and tablespace definitions; you can dump these separately using `pg_dumpall -g`

Comment: Thanks. I see, I guess I am not clear on pg_dump vs pg_dumpall. If I create the db and role manually, then using pg_dump is fine it seems.

Comment: Yes, that is fine.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will use the `pg_dump` output to import into the new pg instance then.